# Squid cache everything for ever

Tags: proxy, cache, squid

I'm running OpenSUSE 13.2 and installed squid via yast. I want to cache everything on my localhost, web pages, ISO, distribution packages.

The problem is that my /var/cache/squid directory stays 20MB, and when I download a ISO it's still downloading it from the server instead of the proxy.

This is my config file:

```
http_port 3128

refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0 1440
refresh_pattern . 1440 20 4320

#refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0

# RFC 1918 possible internal network
# RFC 1918 possible internal network
# RFC 1918 possible internal network
# RFC 4193 local private network range
# RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
# https
# http
# ftp
# https
# gopher
# wais
# unregistered ports
# http-mgmt
# gss-http
# filemaker
# multiling http
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16
acl localnet src fc00::/7
acl localnet src fe80::/10
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80
acl Safe_ports port 21
acl Safe_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 70
acl Safe_ports port 210
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535
acl Safe_ports port 280
acl Safe_ports port 488
acl Safe_ports port 591
acl Safe_ports port 777
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

access_log /var/log/squid/access.log

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 99999 16 256

cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log

cache_mem 99999 MB

cache_mgr webmaster

cache_replacement_policy lru

cache_store_log /var/log/squid/store.log

cache_swap_high 95

cache_swap_low 90

client_lifetime 1 days

connect_timeout 2 minutes

emulate_httpd_log off

error_directory /usr/share/squid/errors/en

ftp_passive on

maximum_object_size 99999 KB

memory_replacement_policy lru

minimum_object_size 0 KB
```

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, do your log files indicate that you're actually using the proxy server? - You've set `maximum_object_size 99999 KB` and I expect ISO images to exceed 99 MB and [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/596890/37681) seems to indicate that the maximum_object_size should be specified above the cache_dir directive.

Comment: Thanks. The ISO is now saved in the cache directory. However the download isn't faster, so I think it is still downloaded from the server. Note that the proxy server and client are on the same machine.